# Cómo traducir texto de un echo en PHP con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo un toggle en mi HTML que cambia el idioma de mi web únicamente asignando un ID al elemento HTML:

```
<!--Toggle-->
      <ul id="no-waves" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg cc navbar d-flex justify-content-around">
         <a class="navbar-brand">Proyecto</a>
         <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" role="button" data-mdb-toggle="dropdown" id="lang" aria-expanded="false"></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-secondary">
               <a class="espanol dropdown-item active" id="ess" >Español</a>
               <a class="english dropdown-item" id="enn" >English</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </ul>
      <!--/Toggle-->
```

**Con éste Javascript:**

```
var strings = {
    espanol: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Idioma",
        ess: "Español",
        enn: "English",
    },
    english: {
        //PRINCIPAL//
        lang: "<i class='fa-duotone fa-earth-americas fa-lg'></i> Language",
        ess: "Spanish",
        enn: "English",
    }
}

$( ".espanol" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to espanol
    localStorage.setItem("lang", "espanol");
    localizeStrings('espanol');
});
$( ".english" ).on( "click", function() {
    // update to english
    localStorage.setItem("lang", "english");
    localizeStrings('english');
});

// default language 
var Lang = localStorage.getItem("lang") || "english";

// localize with default language
localizeStrings(Lang);

// update selected language   
function localizeStrings(strLang) {
    $(strings[strLang]).each(function(key, lang){
        $.each(lang, function(id, string) {
            $("#"+id).html(string);
        });
    });
}
```

Sin embargo tengo un **form**:

```
<form class="text-center" action="#!" method="post">
```

Que me regresa algunos **echo** como éste dentro de una Card en el HTML:

```
echo '{"error":2,"msg":"<font color=#F93154><b>Ejemplo1</b></font> | '.$ejemplo1.'  -Correcto"}';
```

**Y necesito saber cómo puedo traducir el texto de ese echo mediante el código Javascript que ya tengo.**

Lo que he intentado (Sin éxito):
-Agregarle un ID al font y de ahí agregarlo al código Javascript.

```
echo '{"error":2,"msg":"<font id=texto1 color=#F93154><b>Ejemplo1</b></font> | '.$ejemplo1.'  -Correcto"}';
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? **No sé casi nada de Javascript/PHP**, solo HTML Y CSS. He leído que se podría hacer con AJAX pero no sé cómo.

Comment: ***"No sé casi nada de Javascript/PHP, solo HTML Y CSS. He leído que se podría hacer con AJAX pero no sé cómo."***

Vas a tener que aprender un poco antes de poder recargar partes de la página de forma asíncrona.

Comment: Y por dónde puedo empezar?:( Por ahora no me interesaba aprender JS, puesto que quiero seguir practicando más CSS. Uso JS poeque es necesario ):

Comment: Se aprende haciendo cosas, p.e. una calculadora, hay listas de proyectos para principiantes que puedes buscar y muchos sitios de referencia, como https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp o https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Front-end_web_developer